# Cannot find module 'csstype'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new in react with typescript. I installed react, react-dom; then installed @types/react, @types/react-dom, everything fine, everything works, except that I get error `ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:55:22` `Cannot find module 'csstype'`. So I looked to the file in this path, and notice that vscode underlines line - `import * as CSS from 'csstype';` with red line and marks as cannot find module. I tried `yarn add csstype`, `yarn add csstype -D`, did not help. Any idea how fix error? [App works with error].

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using `compilerOptions.moduleResolution: "node"` should fix it

Comment: this worked for me, any ideas on why this happened (this seems to be a recent change somewhere in react I suppose)?

Comment: @types/react added csstype as a dependency which is imported and used for `React.CSSProperties`. So TypeScript won't find it unless `moduleResolution` is set to `node`.

Comment: I resolved it a different way. my tsconfig.json had a specific file to transpile (e.g. `"files": [ "./src/examples/greeter.ts", ]`), i'd included that folder (e.g. `"include": [ "src/examples/**/*" ]`), and i'd excluded the node_modules folder (e.g. `"exclude": [ "node_modules/**/*" ]`), but running `tsc --project tsconfig-examples.json` gave error `Cannot find module 'csstype'`. Solution was to set `"compilerOptions": { "types": []` to disable the default automatic inclusion of all “@types” packages, as recommended in the docs  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: None of the solutions work for me. I already have moduleResolution: node in my tsconfig, and all front end is building well in VC Code, but suddenly VS build started giving this error.